# how to check if database needs auth or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working on a project which allows user to login to a mongodb database. Basically I have

```
db.authenticate(username, password, function(err, isAuthPass) {...}
```

to check if the user pass the authentication. However, sometimes the server doesn't need authentication. If I provide username/password, it will fail. So I need to know how to check auth mode with mongo-native-client. Any idea?

Comment: Honestly you have sort of answered your own question, as in where it fails. If you look at most other "tools" around there ( and that would have been good to state in your question ) that is what they do and produce an error showing the lack of authentication when no credentials are provided. Simply put, trap the error.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get you. Servers like `localhost` usually don't need authentication. If I provide username/password anyway, it will fail anyway. And the call back returns no `err`, only a `true`/`false`. Thus I can't tell if it's because the user provided wrong username/password, or the server doesn't need auth at all.

Comment: What I mean is look at tools like robomongo etc etc. If you try to do something you are not authorized for then they fail, or don't list databases, collections etc. The option is then there to provide credentials that allows access. Please not MongoDB does not "disallow" connection without credentials. It just doesn't allow you to do things.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes that's what they do. I tried some of those tools before, and to me that's the part that confuses me. It feels like a workaround other than a solution. I'm just wondering if there's any other better way to do it. Maybe get the authentication mode before doing it. Trying to make it more like a usual flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I suppose you could just interrogate the database for the config information. This does come with the caveat that you should also be using the "test/fail" methods as discussed before as you would not be able to get this information from a server with authentication enabled that is not running on localhost:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:30000/test',function(err,db) {

  var adminDb = db.admin();

  adminDb.command({ "getCmdLineOpts": 1 },function(err,result) {
    console.log( JSON.stringify( result, undefined, 4 ) );
  });

});
```

That shows the "parsed" options, and it does not matter whether they are actually sent from the command line or picked up from a config file as the output here suggests:

```
{
    "documents": [
        {
            "argv": [
                "mongod",
                "--config",
                "mongod.conf"
            ],
            "parsed": {
                "config": "mongod.conf",
                "net": {
                    "bindIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "port": 30000
                },
                "security": {
                    "authorization": "enabled"
                },
                "storage": {
                    "dbPath": "data"
                },
                "systemLog": {
                    "destination": "file",
                    "logAppend": true,
                    "path": "log/mongod.log"
                }
            },
            "ok": 1
        }
    ],
    "index": 338,
    "messageLength": 338,
    "requestId": 25,
    "responseTo": 3,
    "responseFlag": 8,
    "cursorId": "0",
    "startingFrom": 0,
    "numberReturned": 1
}
```

So here the presence of `"security.authorization.enabled": true` tells you that further operations are going to require authorized credentials to be supplied.

Also see [`getCmdLineOpts`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/) and other [diagnostic information commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/nav-diagnostic/) that should be useful for your tool.

Comment: That's the answer I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes? always use a password. and if you don't need one, like your local environment, you should use a config file for that environment like `./config/dev.js` which has the credentials for that environment.

Comment: I'm working on a tool that helps user execute mongo operations in a web page. I'm not encouraging it but I need to cover the case when user uses it in a environment without authentication (like `localhost`).

Comment: Can you store a config for that user that has a boolean of whether or not they have credentials? like `if ( user.pass )`

Comment: that would be one way but I want to make it simpler. For example, I have several servers in a private network. I may connect to any of them by specifying the server IP. I don't want to specify which needs auth and which doesn't one by one.

Comment: how are you access the password when there is one? Just check if that is null.

Comment: do you mean if the user doesn't provide a password, I don't check it at all? I thought about it, but what if the server needs password, and the user doesn't input one? It will look like the user passed authentication, but he actually doesn't. And later on there will be exceptions.

Comment: oh, you're working directly with user input. I would provide a radio button then or something that says "nopassword" and sets password to null or something. then you can do `if ( nopassword ) //skip auth`

Comment: Yes that would be a way too. I think it would be better if I can check with server if it needs authentication, that would make it even simpler. I know, I'm kind of too serious here. Just want to know if there's a way to do it :)

Comment: well you could login as admin to db and lookup if user has a password.

Comment: hmm, that's kind of impossible. first I don't want the tool to store any credential. secondly the user can connect to any host by specifying the IP of server. I can't know the admin account of all those servers.